How to implement list of interface
What's wrong with the code below?
public interface IMyListItem
{
}

public interface IMyList
{
    IList<IMyListItem> Items { get; }
}

public class MyListItem : IMyListItem
{
}

public class MyList : IMyList
{
    public IList<MyListItem> Items { get; } = new List<MyListItem>();
}

On compile, I get error

CS0738 'MyList' does not implement interface member 'IMyList.Items'. 'MyList.Items' cannot implement 'IMyList.Items' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IList'

What I've tried:
Change MyList class as shown below:
public class MyList : IMyList
{
    public IList<IMyListItem> Items { get; } = (IList<IMyListItem>)new List<MyListItem>();
}

but in this way it's possible to add to MyList an instance of any IMyListItem, for example public class AnotherListItem : IMyListItem, and that doesn't fit the purpose.
Next, I tried to declare IMyList as generic
public interface IMyList<T>
    where T : IMyListItem
{
    IList<T> Items { get; }
}

it looks a bit overhead, but now I can write
public class MyList : IMyList<MyListItem>
{
    public IList<MyListItem> Items { get; } = new List<MyListItem>();
}

and it works as expected
Moving ahead:
I want add to IMyListItem reference to IMyList instance, containing this item. As shown in the first part of question, I can't add reference in this manner:
public interface IMyListItem
{
    IMyList<IMyListItem> List { get; }
}

since I won't be able to implement this later like
public class MyListItem : IMyListItem
{
    public MyList List { get; }
}
// or
public class MyListItem : IMyListItem
{
    public IMyList<MyListItem> List { get; }
}

So using approach with generics, I can write the final code, working as expected, but it does not look good:
public interface IMyListItem<T>
    where T : IMyListItem<T>
{
    IMyList<T> List { get; }
}
public interface IMyList<T>
    where T : IMyListItem<T>
{
    IList<T> Items { get; }
}

public class MyListItem : IMyListItem<MyListItem>
{
    public IMyList<MyListItem> List { get; } // would like "public MyList List { get; }" instead
}

public class MyList : IMyList<MyListItem>
{
    public IList<MyListItem> Items { get; } = new List<MyListItem>();
}

The problems are:

public interface IMyListItem<T> where T : IMyListItem<T> is not clear for feather implementation.
implemented MyListItems property public IMyList<MyListItem> List { get; } allows using any IMyList implementation, but not only MyList, as expected. Should be changed to "public MyList List { get; }" but this does not satisfying interface signature

I Have read this question and it's not the same. That question is completely clear: author wants initialize list of interfaces "A" with a list on concrete class (B:A) List<A> = new List<B>() what is not possible, since not every class implementing A is B. In my case, there is no such collision.

"but in this way it's possible to add to MyList an instance of any IMyListItem" exactly, that's why IList (and List) aren't co-variant. That means you can't just put a Lion into a List<Giraffe>, although both are Animals.

Read the article about variance. The short story is that I could try adding a MyOtherListItem to the IMyList.Items. And this cannot work, since List<MyListItem> cannot contain MyOtherListItem. You might want to change IList to IReadonlyList.
